# Pandoc: HTML-to-Markdown--can I replace elements using templates or scripts?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm successfully converting HTML to Markdown, but elements such as `<span class="cmd">` are preserved and appear in the MD result.

Is there a way, perhaps by using templates or Pandoc scripting, to replace the `<span>` element with `<strong>` or even with asterisks during the HTML-to-Markdown conversion?

For example:

I want to replace

```
<span class="cmd">This content must be bold</span>
```

with

```
<strong>This content must be bold</strong>
```

or

```
*This content must be bold*
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: yes, see http://pandoc.org/scripting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could adapt [this pandoc filter](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters/blob/master/examples/theorem.py). Save this as `cmd_italics.py` and run `pandoc myfile.html -o myfile.md -F cmd_italics.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Strong


def cmd_italics(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'Span':
        [[ident, classes, kvs], contents] = value
        for c in classes:
            if c == "cmd":
                return Strong(contents)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(cmd_italics)
```

You will need the [`pandocfilter` python library](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) installed.