# Pandoc: Python filter to modify definition list terms

Tags: python, json, pandoc

I'm looking for some help in adapting a Pandoc filter (written in Python) to modify Markdown output.

I had help with a similar problem recently ([Pandoc: HTML-to-Markdown--can I replace elements using templates or scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817960/pandoc-html-to-markdown-can-i-replace-elements-using-templates-or-scripts)), but I keep running into errors adapting this new filter.

I'm converting HTML to Markdown (strict) and I want the terms in definition lists to be bold, so I thought I might be able to start with `deflists.py` from [pandocfilters](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters/blob/objects/examples/deflists.py).

This is deflists.py:

```
from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, BulletList, Para, Strong

def deflists(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'DefinitionList':
        return BulletList([tobullet(t, d) for [t, d] in value])

def tobullet(term, defs):
    return([Para([Strong(term)])] + [b for d in defs for b in d])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(deflists)
```

I want to replace a `DefinitionList`, for example (from the AST),

```
DefinitionList
[([Str "TERM",Space,Str "1"],
  [[Plain [Str "DEFN",Space,Str "1"]]])
,([Str "TERM",Space,Str "2"],
  [[Plain [Str "DEFN",Space,Str "2"]]])]
```

so that the definition term is something like `[Strong[Str "TERM",Space,Str "1"]]`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, DefinitionList, Para, Strong

def dlterm_strong(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'DefinitionList':
        return DefinitionList([todlist(t, d) for [t, d] in value])

def todlist(term, defs):
    #return([Para([Strong(term)])] + [b for d in defs for b in d])
    #return(([Str(Strong(term))],[[Para [b for d in defs for b in d]]]))
    return(([Str(Strong(term))],[[b for d in defs for b in d]]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(dlterm_strong)
```

The errors I'm getting are associated with Pandoc expecting a `[a]` and seeing an Object, etc.

My Python, JSON, and Pandoc knowledge is pretty superficial at the moment, so any pointers or suggestion as to what I can try next would be appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Comment: you sure you want the definition terms to be explicitly marked up with `**foo**` in markdown? after all, in almost all output formats (like HTML), you can style them to your liking (e.g. make them bold with CSS)... think semantics, not presentation.

Comment: We're actually converting from DITA to HTML to Markdown, and the Markdown is then converted back to HTML on-the-fly when it's accessed as part of product documentation. It's an unusual process, but yes, I need to have the defn list terms in the Markdown output of the Pandoc conversion marked up with **. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's proper to answer my own question, but with some trial and error and some more time with the Pandoc documentation, I managed to get the filter working:

```
from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, DefinitionList, Para, Strong, Plain

def dlterm_strong(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'DefinitionList':
        return DefinitionList([todlist(t, d) for [t, d] in value])

def todlist(term, defs):
    return(([Strong(term)], defs))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(dlterm_strong)
```